# Migrating from one Trac instance to another

Tags: migration, trac, redmine, ticket-system

I want to move tickets from one trac instance to another. Is there some utility that will help me do this? The current instance is running on my server using a sqllite db. The instance that I want to move to is on sourcerepo. Are there any utilities that can help me migrate these tickets?

Since sourcerepo also provides a redmine installation, I wouldn't mind if I could move tickets from trac to redmine.

Comment: Is there a CSV export or something maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at what the [Trac wiki](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki) has to say about [migrating data between Trac installations](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracMigrate).